# iOS: make array of objects move across the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I am trying to make multiple UILabels (using a `for` loop and inserting them into an array) move horizontally across the screen. I have the labels, I have the array, but I cannot figure out how to use animations to get them to move. I tried using `[self.array setValue @0 forKey:@"XPOSITION"];` but I do not know how to write the x position. Is there no real way to change the x position in an array? Will I have to make each one its own individual thing and use `object.frame = CGRectMake(newx,y,w,h);` which seems a bit tedious? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could use `setCenter:` instead of `.frame`. I also recommend using the `set___:` methods as opposed to using the `.` operator since going through the method ensures that you do not change anything when the object is not expecting a change. Plus you may get unwanted behavior that takes an absurd amount of time to debug.

Comment: If they are going to move the same amount, why can't you just add them to a UIView and move the view itself?

Comment: yes but is there a way to animate the array? When I try using `setCenter` with the array like `[self.array setCenter:CGPointMake(newx,y)];` is says "No visible @interface for 'NSMutableArray' declares the selector 'setCenter'

Comment: @Kiley `setCenter:` is a method on the `UILabel`s, not the array. It is simply a way to replace your `.frame = ...` approach by using less information (only 2 variables instead of 4).

Comment: @GurtejSingh unfortunately they are not the only things on the view, and I do not wish to move everything over.

Comment: @Aderis if I have 20 to 30 items being moved, I would prefer not to have to write-out each one, hence I asked the question. I know how to move them individually, but thank you for your input on `setCenter:` vs `.frame`

Comment: @Aderis Using a setter method is exactly the same as using the dot notation. The dot notation is just shorthand.

Comment: Ok. I would rather put the labels in a separate view and move that over. But would be certainly interested to know other techniques.

Comment: @Aderis if you would like to talk about which is better, it might be best to begin a discussion on the topic instead of commenting on a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Aderis' advice about setting the center, you have to use a for loop to set the center of each label.

```
for (UILabel *label in self.array) {
    CGPoint oldCenter = label.center;
    label.center = CGPoint(oldCenter.x + 20, oldCenter.y);
}
```

Where you would change `20` to be whatever value you actually wanted to change the `x` coordinate by.

If you want to have it animated, you can use this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
    for (UILabel *label in self.array) {
        CGPoint oldCenter = label.center;
        label.center = CGPoint(oldCenter.x + 20, oldCenter.y);
    }
}];
```

Where you would replace 0.2 with the length in seconds you want the animation to last.

Comment: yes but if there are 20 or so labels, I would prefer not to have to do each individually, hence I asked about moving an array of objects. I will definitely use this method here in other portions of my project!

Comment: "Moving an array of objects" is the same thing as "moving every object in an array". Unfortunately, there isn't a way to do something to every object in an array without iterating through the array.

Comment: @Kiley If, when you say you "don't want to do each individually", you mean that you would write the above code 20 times, you don't have to. You can simply create an array with all of the x offsets, and instead of using a for each loop, use a for loop with a counter. Then you can simply apply the offset at index `i`, to the label at index `i`.

Comment: Thank you @Aderis I did not realize you could use `for` loops inside of animations! That answered my question!

Answer (score 1):

You should try using the builtin animation capabilities of `UIView`. You can do the following code:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

for (UIView* view in myArray)
{
    [view setCenter:thisViewsTargetCenterPoint];
}

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

In the for loop, you should do all the UI positioning changes you want, and once you call `commitAnimations`, UIKit will do all the position changes through animations.

Comment: so in the case where I have other objects in the view I do not wish to move, is there a way to create a view on top of the initial view that does the movement, or is this not possible?

Comment: @Kiley You do not need to worry about that with this code. `UIView` is the class, not a specific object, so it doesn't matter which superviews the moving views are in. Also, if you have an array that contains all the views that need to be moved, and only those views, then that is the array that will replace `myArray` in my code above.

Comment: Using your code it set the center of each individual item in the array to the one given, not just the general view, but it's definitely a start in the right direction!

Comment: @Kiley Isn't that what you wanted? Can you further explain what you want, as apparently I did not understand your goal fully?

Comment: I wanted them to move horizontally across the screen consistently--- something like what you would see in a java for loop where inside the loop you would put value.x += 1; I hope I explained it correctly now!